# Ubuntu Lucid goes to sleep and never wakes up

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I have upgraded from Ubuntu Karma to Lucid, and it seems I have replaced one problem with another.

With Karma, the screen occasionally froze unexpectedly, forcing a REISUB. I am using a DELL monitor with an NVIDEA twin monitor card (working with one monitor).

Since I upgraded, these screen freezes appear to have disappeared (I don't know for sure yet - since I only upgraded 2 days ago). However, one annoying occurence is that when I leave the machine idle for a period of time and it goes to sleep. I am unable to wake it up - as teh keyboard/mouse is unresponsive (well until/unless I do a REISUB). All I get is a black screen which pulsates between pitch black and "grey" every 2 seconds or so.

I noticed though that if I catch the machine BEFORE it falls asleep - i.e. just as the monitor starts to dim, I can avert this farce. Also, when I put the machine into hibernate. It enters this same trance-like state, where the only way to wake it up is to do a REISUB.

Does anyone know how I may resolve this, as it really is getting quite tiresome.

Comment: Try doing a clean install (especially since you are using proprietary drivers). And, BTW, it's Karmic, not Karma, and NVIDIA, not NVIDEA.

Answer (score 0):

There was a big switch in from Karmic to Lucid where they chose to replace the closed source nVidia drivers with the [nouveau open clone](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/). From back in Lucid beta, the nouveau code seemed to have issues, especially on laptops. Thus many people [choose to use the nVidia drivers instead](http://www.uluga.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8934650).

I expect that nouveau will be a Good Thing once it has been beaten on sufficiently.